# Adding a new class in my namespace results in "the type or namespace could not be found"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm just trying to do a very basic thing here. I'm using Sublime Text and developer command prompt from VS. When I add a "Comet"-class to spaceobj.cs, the compiler can't find the new class. I tried pasting the code to a friend of mine, and he was able to run it without any issues. I've seen some posts about configuring build path to the full .NET Framework or something? But how does one go about doing such a thing when I'm not using the VS IDE, but only a text editor? And it's so weird that it only happens with the Comet class and not the others...

Here's the code at least :

Mainprog.cs :

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using SpaceSim;

class Astronomy {
    public static void Main()
    {
        ArrayList a = new ArrayList();

        a.Add(new Star("Sun"));
        a.Add(new Comet("Comet #1"));

        for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++) {
            SpaceObject obj = (SpaceObject)(a[i]);
            obj.Draw();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Spaceobj.cs :

```
using System;

namespace SpaceSim {
    public class SpaceObject {

        protected String name;

        public SpaceObject(String _name) {
            name = _name;
        }

        public virtual void Draw() {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
    }

    public class Star:SpaceObject {
        public Star(String _name) : base(_name) {}

        public override void Draw() {
            Console.Write("Star : ");
            base.Draw();
        }
    }


    public class Comet : SpaceObject {
        public Comet(String _name) : base(_name) {}

        public override void Draw() {
            Console.Write("Comet : ");
            base.Draw();
        }
    }  
}
```

And in the developer command prompt I write :

```
    csc /target:library spaceobj.cs
    csc /target:exe /r:spaceobj.dll mainprog.cs
```

Comment: Start with a new, empty directory. Copy these two files into that directory. Run those commands in that new directory. Do you still have this error? When you open the files, are the contents exactly as you've described? Most likely guess would be that you're editing a different `spaceobj.cs` file than the one you think you are and/or you're working in a different directory to the one that you think you are.

Comment: Yeah, I tried with the new empty directory. That worked. But I had only on spaceobj.cs file on my computer at the time, so I don't really get how it happened.